# Dataflow - Azure - isDecimal

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have been trying to do a datatype check in a decimal column of a file by using the Data Flow from Azure Data Factory, but it is not working as expected. My issue is the following one:

I want to check if the number 121012132.12 is a decimal, so I am using the data flow's derived column and writing the expression: isDecimal('121012132.12', '17.2'). The output has always  been false, even if I change the precision or replace a dot with a comma, etc. I have tried many different ways, but without success. I realized that if I shorten the number, it recognizes it as decimal. Moreover, If I try to convert it into decimal, it works well (toDecimal('121012132.12', 17, 2)

Please, can anyone tell me if there is a different way to do this check?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This happens because for decimal the precision is defaulted to (10,2).

try **isFloat('121012132.12')**  this will work

Thanks
Hijesh

Comment: Hi Hijesh, it might work in this way, but I cannot understand why I am not able to use isDecimal('121012132.12','17.2') ... as far as I understand the precision part of the code is adjustable, and if I try to convert the number into Decimal by using toDecimal('121012132.12',17,2) it works well.

Answer (score 0):

1. In azure data type check does not work as we expect
2. isFloat(100) = true
3. isFloat(100.1) -> true
4. isDecimal(100) -> true
5. isDecimal(100.1) -> true

   Try below

**`iif(length(coalesce(split(VALUE,'.')[2],''))>1, true(), false())`**